# Access remote VLAN over IPsec VPN using Zyxel routers

Tags: vpn, vlan, zyxel

I have a **central** site with a *Zyxel Zywall 310* and a **remote** site with a *Zyxel USG 20w*. I also have a working IPsec VPN between the two sites.

PCs on `LAN1` of the **remote** site can access *Server1* on `LAN1` of the **central** site, but not *Server2* on `VLAN4` of the **central** site.

What rules would I need to add to allow PCs at the **remote** site (behind the USG 20w) to access *Server2* on `VLAN4` at the **central** site (behind the Zywall 310)?

Here's what the network looks like:

[image]

I suspect the solution may involve either Policy or Static Route rules (I currently have none set, though I've tinkered with them a bit, but was unable to get anything working).

Comment: Post IP assigned to central router on lan1 and vpn4, server 2 ip config and firewall configuration on routers. Where you where you have routing between lan1 and vlan4?

Answer (score 0):

add route on remote router to `VLAN4` network `192.168.40.0/24` by central router ip `192.168.10.x`, allow traffic from `192.168.12.0/24` to `192.168.40.0/24` on central router

Comment: Like I said, I've tried adding a route in the **remote** router, both as a Policy Route and a Static Route. Neither worked. The **central** site router has a security rule allowing traffic from _any_ to _VLAN4_ .  All LANs and VLANs on the **central** router can access _VLAN4_ just fine.

Comment: Can you post this firewall rules? You can also do alternative config adding 2nd VPN tunnel between remote lan1 and central vlan4